# Facebook Graph Api in Unity not granting email permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

So i'm trying to wrap my head around the Facebook API for Unity, and I think i'm starting to get the hang of it...until this

```
FB.Login ("public_profile, user_photos, email", AuthCallBack);
```

so as you can see I obviously ask for the email permission, yet when I try to call it in Unity

```
Dictionary<string, string> emailDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"email", ""}};

        FB.API( "me?fields=email", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, FBGetEmail, emailDict);

        print ("emailDict " + emailDict.Keys);
```

This only yields me my userid. I did some further digging into the Graph Explorer with the same newly generated access token which I got from the app which revealed the following

```
The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'email' permission.

{"id": "952814180948",}
```

so my question is... does anyone know//can anyone see what i'm doing wrong to not be able to get the email permission? Since the problem is obviously in the initial request when when the access token is generated. I know the permissions are working as I'm able to pull and use my profile pic..just not the email :'(

Comment: have you tried to remove the app from your facebook authorized list? Then launch again your application, it should ask again for the permissions and the new one should be added. I think I went thru this problem once... 

... I tried to add "likes" permission to my app, and didn't worked until I went to facebook and removed the app from my authorized app list. then I tried again and "like" permissions where displayed in the list.

Comment: I just tried that, re-granted permissions, but alas, still no email :(

Answer (score 6):

So I figured it out!!! The answer is nestled in a single line in the facebook docs. Basically, when using the authentication tokens in Unity's editor mode, It allows you go "get token" But this generated token has just some default permissions.

You need to actually go to the graph explorer, and at the top set your app to YOUR APP ( it wasnt clear, I thought that it made you go to your app page NOT generate access tokens for your app).

Once I did that, I was able to generate new access tokens with the permissions I wanted by using the Get Access Token Button on the graph explorer page.

Oish! Two whole days just to figure that out.

Comment: Need better explanation with examples