# javascript and Facebook login API: get the user's email

Tags: javascript, facebook

I created a website with FB authentication a few months ago and it worked with this:

```
function setElements(isLoggedIn){
    if(isLoggedIn){
        FB.api('/me?fields=name,email',function(response){
            if(response && !response.error){
                $.ajax({                                      
                    url: 'ajax.php',        
                    type:"POST",
                    data: { name: response.name, email: response.email},
                    success: function(response){        
                    } 
                }); 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a new one. It still works with the same script but instead of getting both the name and email now, I only get the email.

if I log into the console "response:name", I get it but the "response.email" shows "undefined".

Maybe they changed their methods to get the email since a few months (for privacy reasons or whatever).
Can someone tell me how I can fix this, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Their [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) returns the expected data. Did you look into the Network tab and look at the raw response and see if the right data is being sent / received?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry but I'm just a dilettante. I don't know what that Network tab is and how to check what's sent and returned.

Comment: Hit F12 and you will get the developers tools window. There should be a tab labeled "Network". While that is up execute your code again and you should see a request to facebook. Clicking on that request should open up a side view with data like headers, response, etc

Comment: Header: "access_token:xxx
fields: name,email
method: get
pretty: 0
sdk: joey
suppress_http_code: 1

Response: 
{
    "name": "myname",
    "id": "123456"
}

Comment: So I ask for the name and email (header tab) and it spits the name and id (preview tab), for whatever reason.
This is with the Safari dev tools (on Mac).
I think the id is automatically retrieved whatever you ask for, but "email" doesn't seem to get anything (anymore).

Answer (score 1):

So this gave me the answer and, indeed, it wasn't clear at all.
It wasn't about the code, it was about the Facebook Dev interface.

[Facebook Graph Api in Unity not granting email permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272967/facebook-graph-api-in-unity-not-granting-email-permission)

Problem solved, thank you.

PS: Most documents of the API are misleading as they say that the email doesn't need any permission as it is part of the standard profile data (name, id, email). But it needs one and there is only one place where you can change that.